# Remove Chapter numbers, keeps Section numbers

Tags: sectioning, numbering, chapters

I do not know how to remove the Chapter numbers in front of each chapter (`Chapter #`), and in the same time keep the section numbers. So I need something like the following:

Chapter name

1.1 First section

1.2 Second section

Also, numbering of my photos is a little weird. Right now, I have Photo 2.1 (since the photo is in Section 2). I just want normal numbering such as Photo 1, Photo 2 etc.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! This depends on the documentclass. One way, most likely, is to use `\chapter*{Foo}`, those are unnumbered. Having unnumbered chapters and numbered sections are a little bit weird, however, in my point of view

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to set `\thechapter` to nothing, i.e. `{}`, but this will leave `\thesection` with a trailing `.` and the chapter heading will still show `Chapter` (or `\chaptername`).

To get a continous figure numbering, the figure counter has to be kicked out of the chapter reset list, i.e. use `\counterwithout{figure}{chapter}`. then.

Since the question is a little bit unclear, I don't change `\@makechapterhead` right now.

```
\documentclass{book}


\usepackage{chngcntr}%


\renewcommand{\thechapter}{}%
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section}}%
\counterwithout{figure}{chapter}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\chapter{First chapter}

\section{First section}



\begin{figure}
\caption{Dummy figure}
\end{figure}

\chapter{Second chapter}

\section{First section in 2nd chapter}

\begin{figure}
\caption{Another dummy figure}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

Comment: You might use `\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section}}%` instead. Of course there remains the problem of `\chaptername`.

Comment: @Bernard: Well, this would leave the number of the chapter in the numbering. One could do this, if this is requested

Comment: The O.P. seemed  to request it, precisely.

Comment: @Bernard: You're right. I disregarded the list. Thanks, I will change.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to do it with `titlesec` (albeit there seems to be some problem with the latest version: I wouldn't have done it exactly this way with the previous version of titlesec):

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} \usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\chapter}[block]{\bfseries\Huge}{}{0em}{}
\titleformat{\section}[hang]{\bfseries\Large}{}{1em}{\thesection\enspace}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\chapter{First chapter}

\section{First section}

\begin{figure}
\caption{Dummy figure}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\thesection` seems to include the chapter numbers with it...